# Divide et impera sum of the elements of an array bug

Tags: c++, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I wrote the following function to calculate the sum of all the elements in a vector using the divide et impera method

```
int Sum(std::vector<int> v, int left, int right)
{
int mid = (left + right) / 2;

if (left >= right)
    return v[mid];
else
    return Sum(v, left, mid - 1) + Sum(v, mid + 1, right);
}

//in main:
vector <int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

cout << Sum(v, 0, v.size() - 1);
```

However in the given example it outputs 37 instead of 55. I went through it with a debugger and it seems to skip certain numbers. I tried changing `left >= right` to `left > right` and it still gives me a wrong answer (56) although I think it should be `left => right` logically speaking.

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: Next time, please post your code as a [mcve], like [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0464efdc90edb5a4).  Your code is missing `include` headers, and we don't know if other relevant things are missing from `main`.  If you leave it to someone to fill in these gaps, there is a chance that the filled in code does not match what you are compiling and running.

Comment: `Sum(v, left, mid - 1) + Sum(v, mid, right);` and this works in `O(n^2)` becuase you copy vector, pass it by const reference: `int Sum(const std::vector<int>& v, int left, int right)`

Comment: It seems like it's time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. It's also useful to jot down notes while debugging on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main problem: The recursion excludes `mid` from both sub-sums.

Secondary problem: It may happen that `left>right` (though with reasonable initial input, at worst `left == right + 1`). In this case you want to return `0`.

So perhaps

```
if ( left > right ) 
   return 0;
else
   return Sum(v, left, mid-1) + v[mid] + Sum(v, mid+1, right);
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrong is here,

```
return Sum(v, left, mid - 1) + Sum(v, mid + 1, right);
```

You are missing to add `v[mid]`. So, change it,

```
if (left >= right)
    return v[left]; // v[mid] also helps.

return Sum(v, left, mid) + Sum(v, mid + 1, right);
```

Comment: What exactly did you change, and *why* will that change solve the problem? Please explain and don't just show code that encourages [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Also please refresh [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `return Sum(v, left, mid - 1)+ v[mid] + Sum(v, mid + 1, right);`
This one returns 70 (too much). The other two work fine though, thank you.

Comment: hope, the answer is now ok.

Answer (score 0):

`Sum` should be like this:

```cpp
int Sum(const std::vector<int>& v, int left, int right)  // pass vector by const reference
{
int mid = (left + right) / 2;

if (left == right)  // there's no need to check whether left > right
                    // if you call function with left <= right
    return v[mid];
else
    return Sum(v, left, mid) + Sum(v, mid + 1, right);  // you have missed mid
}
```

In your version you also copy vector during recursion, try to call your function like this:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v(100'000, 1);  // digit separator comes since C++14
Sum(v, 0, v.size() - 1);
```

and you'll see how long it takes